# How to pick with css multiple select tags that has at least one option selected?

Tags: css, css-selectors

When the `:has()` selector comes to life this will be possible of course, but is there any way to select `<select>`'s with at least one option selected. Maybe using the `[value=""]` selector?

I wouldn't ask this if it wasn't because picking options changes the value of the select, so I think there may be a way through that path. Any ideas?

Example:

```css
.select[value] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>value 1</option>
  <option>value 2</option>
  <option>value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You would style the `:selected` option instead. The `<select>` element is just a container.

Comment: @Vandervals Would it be fine if I can provide a simple JavaScript solution?

Comment: I believe this is not possible on CSS without `:has()` since even if you can check for selected option, there's no way to select the parent (e.g. `<`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it work using the `required` attribute on the `select` element and using `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes in your CSS.

I made a demo below.  The method using a single-choice select is kinda hacky because you have to insert an empty `option`, but the multiple-choice `select` works rather nicely.  Tested in Chrome, FF, and IE11.

```css
select:invalid {
 border: solid 2px red;
}

select:invalid + label::after {
  content: "(Please make a selection)";
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  font-style: italic;
}

select:valid {
 border: solid 2px green;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<select id="single" required>
 <option selected disabled></option>
 <option>Blue</option>
 <option>Red</option>
</select>
<label for="single">Single Choice</label>

<select id="multiple" required multiple>
 <option>Blue</option>
 <option>Red</option>
</select>
<label for="multiple">Multiple Choice</label>
```

Comment: Yes, the only issue is that you must use `required`.  But it sounds like in your situation it's required anyway!

Comment: I agree - if you're trying to target a select with no selection, chances are that it's supposed to be a required control. Of course, there's the possibility that it's not *required* per se though still worth highlighting, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Neither [Selectors 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors), [Selectors 4](http://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4), [CSS UI 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3) nor [CSS UI 4](http://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4) offer any pseudo-classes for matching `<select>` elements based on any specific criteria. The only pseudo-class that comes close is `:checked`, which applies to `<option>` elements.

With `:has()`, therefore, it would probably be as trivial as `select[multiple]:has(> :checked)`. Other than that, there are no selector-based alternatives. While `<select>` does have a DOM `.value` property, it doesn't have a `value` attribute (since the selection of a `<select>` is already expressed via the `selected` attribute on `<option>`), so you won't be able to use an attribute selector.